# Is sharing non-consumable In-App Purchases between two different apps against App Store guidelines?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, ios7

I have two different apps with some overlaps in functionality. As a result, some of the In-App purchases in both the apps are the same. So I want the user to be able to use a feature which he purchased from one app in another app as well.

For example, if there are two games, one a car racing game and another a bike racing game, and the user buys a race track as an IAP in one of the apps, then he must be able to play on the track in both the apps.

The question, Is this behaviour allowed by Apple. According to one of the [App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies), **"Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected".**

*If it is indeed allowed and it has been already implemented, what is the best way to achieve this?*
Please note, one of the apps was created long time back and hence the **Bundle Seed IDs of both the apps are different**.
Here's what I have tried:

- Since the Team IDs of both the apps are the same, I was able to share In-App purchase data between the apps using iCloud. But is it safe to store the purchased *product identifiers* in the iCloud? Could it be easily hacked?
- Since the Bundle Seed IDs of the apps are different, I couldn't share data between the apps using Key Chain Items.
- I could create custom URLs for the apps and let one app open the other and know the IAPs made in that. But that will lead to unnecessary user interaction. This is my last resort now!

Comment: *Could product identifiers in iCloud be easily hacked ?* well, every Internet-connected will have chance of being hacked.

Comment: Or instead of hacked, the question should have been, Could it be easily modified? NSUserDefaults of an app could be easily modified by the user. Similarly could iCloud data of an app be easily modified?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's guide: [Getting Started with In-App Purchase on iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf), sharing in-app purchases between apps is not allowed.